# Using Select Query inside a while loop in php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to Print some data from 2 tables when i try to execute 2nd select query inside while loop its not showing any result 
My query is

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM buses");
echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>Sno</td>";
echo "<td>Route #</td>";
echo "<td>Bus _Type</td>";
echo "<td>Timing</td>";
echo "<td>From</td>";
echo "</tr>";
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>"."<center>".$row['sno']."</center>"."</td>";
echo "<td>"."<center>".$row['Route']."</center>"."</td>";
echo "<td>"."<center>".$row['Bus_type']."</center>"."</td>";
echo "<td>"."<center>".substr($row['Timing'],0,5)."</center>"."</td>";
$route=$row['Route'];
$query2=mysql_query("SELECT fromcity FROM routes WHERE Route= '$route' ");
$row2=mysql_fetch_array($query2);
echo "<td>"."<center>".$row2['fromcity']."</center>"."</td>";
```

routes Table

[image]

buses table

[image]

Result

[image: Not showing Data Of From city Field]

Comment: Oh god, the markup... When doing blocks of code just leave 4 spaces in front of it, don't use back ticks... I've done the first three lines for you. Edit your question to tidy it up please.

Comment: I retrive a the value in $route variable like this                        $route=$row['Route'];

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says [your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can continue with your solution but for efficiency sake, you shouldn't be doing a SELECT inside a loop, you should be using an SQL JOIN.

Your query should be joining the two tables on the Route field:

```
SELECT * FROM buses b
INNER JOIN routes r ON b.Route = r.Route;
```

No extra queries will be needed inside the loop as you'll have access to the fromcity from this query.  You may want to specifically declare the fields in the SELECT rather than using `*`.

Comment: how can i print the result of this query

Comment: Well, how do you print the results of any query?  `print_r(mysql_fetch_array($query))` would print out the first row so you can see the contents.  I highly urge you to listen to the other advice and stop using mysql_ functions though.  Learn PDO.

Comment: i tried to print the result but its not showing value of fromcity